# Why won't this output anything?

Tags: javascript

For some reason I can't seem to get this program to output and also can't think of what I might have done wrong. I've tried it in a few different browsers and keep getting the same result, which is nothing happens

```html
<html>
  <title>Activity</title>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function outputData(studentData) {
        var studentFirstName = studentData.firstname.value;
        var studentLastName = studentData.lastname.value;
        var studentAge = studentData.age.value;
        var sA = document.GetElementById("A").checked;
        var sWR = document.GetElementById("WR").checked;
        var sC = document.GetElementById("C").checked;
        var sP = document.GetElementById("P").checked;

        document.write("" + studentFirstName + "</br>" + studentLastName + "</br>" + studentAge + "</br>");
        if (sA) document.write("" + Anthropology + "</br>");
        if (sWR) document.write("" + World Religion + "</br>");
        if (sC) document.write("" + Criminology + "</br>");
        if (sP) document.write("" + Philosophy + "</br>");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <p>Enter Student Details</br></p>
  <form name="studentData" action="" method="GET">
    First name:<input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
    <br>Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>
    <br>Age:<input type="text" name="age" value=""><br><br>
    Select your choice of subjects:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="A" name="subject" value="Anthropology">Anthropology<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="WR" name="subject" value="World Religion">World Religion<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="C" name="subject" value="Criminology">Criminology<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="P" name="subject" value="Philosophy">Philosophy<br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="outputData(this.form)"><br>
  </form>
</html>
```

Sorry if this has a really simple solution, I'm only just started learning HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code:

- The function `GetElementByID` should actually be `getElementById`.
- The `Anthropology` in your `document.write()` is an string and should be treated as such. See the code below.
- You are also missing the body tag

  ```
  <html>
  <title>Activity</title>
  <head>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

          function outputData(studentData){
              var studentFirstName = studentData.firstname.value;
              var studentLastName = studentData.lastname.value;
              var studentAge = studentData.age.value;

              var sA = document.getElementById("A").checked;
              var sWR = document.getElementById("WR").checked;
              var sC = document.getElementById("C").checked;
              var sP = document.getElementById("P").checked;

              document.write("" + studentFirstName + "</br>" 
                                + studentLastName + "</br>" 
                                + studentAge + "</br>");

              if(sA) document.write("Anthropology</br>");

              if(sWR) document.write("World Religion</br>");

              if(sC) document.write("Criminology</br>");

              if(sP) document.write("Philosophy</br>");
          }

      </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Enter Student Details</br></p>

  <form name = "studentData" action = "" method = "GET">

      First name:<input type = "text" name = "firstname" value = ""><br>

      <br>Last name:<input type = "text" name = "lastname" value = ""><br>

      <br>Age:<input type = "text" name = "age" value = ""><br><br>

      Select your choice of subjects:<br>

      <input type = "checkbox" id = "A" name= "subject" value = "Anthropology">Anthropology<br>

      <input type = "checkbox" id = "WR" name= "subject" value = "World Religion">World Religion<br>

      <input type = "checkbox" id = "C" name="subject" value ="Criminology">Criminology<br>

      <input type = "checkbox" id = "P" name="subject" value ="Philosophy">Philosophy<br>

      <input type = "button" value = "Submit" onClick = "outputData(this.form)"><br>

  </form>
  ```

---

If you wanted to get the values of the checkboxes instead then use the following JS (in the `script` tag instead):

```
 function outputData(studentData){

        var studentFirstName = studentData.firstname.value;
        var studentLastName = studentData.lastname.value;
        var studentAge = studentData.age.value;

        var sA = document.getElementById("A");
        var sWR = document.getElementById("WR");
        var sC = document.getElementById("C");
        var sP = document.getElementById("P");

        document.write("" + studentFirstName + "</br>" 
                          + studentLastName  + "</br>" 
                          + studentAge       + "</br>");

        if(sA.checked) document.write("" + sA.value + "</br>");

        if(sWR.checked) document.write("" + sWR.value + "</br>");

        if(sC.checked) document.write("" + sC.value + "</br>");

        if(sP.checked) document.write("" + sP.value + "</br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is your only problem, but you are missing `<body>` ... `</body>` tags, after your `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code formatting (`GetElementById` should be `getElementById`, missing `<body>`, etc). But I feel like what is preventing your code from running, is the fact that you are treating strings as a variable in your conditions.

```
if (sWR) document.write("" + World Religion + "</br>");
```

Should be quoted...

```
if (sWR) document.write("" + 'World Religion' + "</br>");
```

Also, using `<br>` for every line is a lazy way of doing things. You should really be building proper HTML and wrapping your elements correctly based on the layout you need. Always pair `<label>` with your `<input>` tags, and leverage CSS to your advantage.

Look into the bootstrap library because it makes styling forms much easier and has a lot of other capabilities.

Take a look at the final product below...

```css
.form-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.selection {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.input-group>label,
.input-group>input {
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submit-button {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Activity</title>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function outputData(studentData) {
      var studentFirstName = studentData.firstname.value;
      var studentLastName = studentData.lastname.value;
      var studentAge = studentData.age.value;
      var sA = document.getElementById("A").checked;
      var sWR = document.getElementById("WR").checked;
      var sC = document.getElementById("C").checked;
      var sP = document.getElementById("P").checked;

      document.write("" + studentFirstName + "</br>" + studentLastName + "</br>" + studentAge + "</br>");
      if (sA) document.write("" + 'Anthropology' + "</br>");
      if (sWR) document.write("" + 'World Religion' + "</br>");
      if (sC) document.write("" + 'Criminology' + "</br>");
      if (sP) document.write("" + 'Philosophy' + "</br>");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="form-title">Enter Student Details</p>
  <form name="studentData" action="" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>First name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label>Age:</label>
      <input type="text" name="age" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="selection">
      Select your choice of subjects:
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="A" name="subject" value="Anthropology">
      <label>Anthropology</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="WR" name="subject" value="World Religion">
      <label>World Religion</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="C" name="subject" value="Criminology">
      <label>Criminology</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="checkbox" id="P" name="subject" value="Philosophy">
      <label>Philosophy</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="outputData(this.form)" class="submit-button">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Change GetElementById to **getElementById**
2. use checkbox value instead of typing it manually.

> var sA = document.getElementById("A");

This will get the input value field/console.log(sA) - you will see the values in there

> if(sA.checked) document.write("" + sA.value + "");

Activity

```
<head>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function outputData(studentData){

            var studentFirstName = studentData.firstname.value;

            var studentLastName = studentData.lastname.value;

            var studentAge = studentData.age.value;

            var sA = document.getElementById("A");

            var sWR = document.getElementById("WR");

            var sC = document.getElementById("C");

            var sP = document.getElementById("P");

            document.write("" + studentFirstName + "</br>" + studentLastName + "</br>" + studentAge + "</br>");

            if(sA.checked) document.write("" + sA.value + "</br>");


            if(sWR.checked) document.write("" + sWR.value + "</br>");

            if(sC.checked) document.write("" + sC.value + "</br>");

            if(sP.checked) document.write("" + sP.value + "</br>");
        }

    </script>

</head>

<p>Enter Student Details</br></p>

<form name = "studentData" >

    First name:<input type = "text" name = "firstname" value = ""><br>

    <br>Last name:<input type = "text" name = "lastname" value = ""><br>

    <br>Age:<input type = "text" name = "age" value = ""><br><br>

    Select your choice of subjects:<br>

    <input type = "checkbox" id = "A" name= "subject" value = "Anthropology">Anthropology<br>

    <input type = "checkbox" id = "WR" name= "subject" value = "World Religion">World Religion<br>

    <input type = "checkbox" id = "C" name="subject" value ="Criminology">Criminology<br>

    <input type = "checkbox" id = "P" name="subject" value ="Philosophy">Philosophy<br>

    <input type = "button" value = "Submit" onClick = "outputData(this.form)"><br>

</form>
```